# Why Does My Model Accuracy Go Down With More Data?

Tags: r, cart, validation, accuracy, caret

I am using R and the caret package.

My code is very straight forward.

```
set.seed(2112)
trainingDataset <- read.csv("Input.txt")
train_control <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number = 10, repeats = 3)
fit <- train(eval ~ ., trControl = train_control, method = "treebag", data = trainingDataset)
```

---

**My first run has 928 data points**

When I key in fit, I get:

```
Bagged CART 

928 samples 

158 predictors 

  2 classes: 'SELL', 'BUY' 

No pre-processing

Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 3 times) 

Summary of sample sizes: 836, 835, 835, 835, 835, 835, ... 

Resampling results

  Accuracy  Kappa  Accuracy SD  Kappa SD

  0.694     0.368  0.0544       0.113
```

---

**My second run has 1436 data points**

When I key in fit, I get:

```
Bagged CART 

1436 samples

 158 predictors

   2 classes: 'SELL', 'BUY' 

No pre-processing

Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 3 times) 

Summary of sample sizes: 1292, 1294, 1292, 1293, 1292, 1292, ... 

Resampling results

  Accuracy  Kappa  Accuracy SD  Kappa SD

  0.678     0.34   0.0457       0.0962
```

---

Any thoughts on why a 50% increase in the amount of data would result in a drop in the accuracy of the model?

Is my model not very good? Am I overfitting?

Comment: I'm guessing that you're overfitting. I always assume my accuracy will decrease when I increase my n.

Comment: .694 == .678, with a margin of error

Comment: Take a look at the standard devitions of your accuracy then you see that is was already plausible that your original accuracy was actually lower than what you estimated with the 2nd model where the error margin becomes narrower: 0.694 +/- 0.0544 and 0.678 +/-  0.0457 mean there is basically no (significant) change, as Hong Ooi pointed out.

Comment: @AndrewBrēza Do not assume that. Over fitting is one end; the other end is under feeding your model with not sufficient data. There is an optimum.

Comment: Is this two different datasets? or is the smaller dataset a subset of the larger? If so, how was the subset choosen?

Comment: You always need to plot your learning curves and find the sweet point.
Here's [link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_learning_curve.html) to nice docs on *sklearn*.

Comment: I believe @kjetilbhalvorsen's comment needs to be addressed, and until then, am voting to close as "needs more details".